# Meteor role do not exist inside a method but in another

Tags: javascript, meteor, alanning-roles

I'm using the alanning role package in a meteor application.
I created an admin role and I'm setting this role in another method whithout problem.

But in a method I use : `Roles.setUserRoles( userID, 'admin', groupID );`.
I get a Error: `Role 'admin' does not exist`. but I know admin exists and I am using the same line in an other methods.

So my question is: What could lead to this error ? (a role do not exist in a method but in another)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use 'addUsersToRoles' or maybe something's wrong with the groupID. It works well for me with that code:

```
Roles.addUsersToRoles(userId, 'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
```

or to remove:

```
Roles.removeUsersFromRoles(userId, 'admin', Roles.GLOBAL_GROUP);
```

And in a Markup for e.g.:

```
{{#if isInRole 'admin' }}
You're Admin.
{{/if}}
```

Comment: Hi @NRiebesel ! The thing is that I'm using this role in other methods whithout problem. I'm using setRole instead of remove because the user can have 2 others roles and I want to set him only one.
So my question is more what can make that he role admin that I'm using in others methods do not work in this particular method :/

Answer (score 0):

Do you import the faulty method in the same place as the first one?

Comment: Yes... :/ I will try to call the other method instead of trying to change the role in this method...